# iptables Applying firewall rules

Tags: centos, iptables

I have two servers, when I restart iptables on the first server it does "Applying firewall rules" but on the second does'nt. What's the problem with the second server ?

First server:

> [root@test ~]# service iptables restart
>
> iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
>
> iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter         [  OK  ]
>
> iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
>
> iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]

Second server:

> [root@test ~]# service iptables restart
>
> iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
>
> iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: nat             [  OK  ]
>
> iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]

Thank you.

Comment: What does service iptables status say ? Are there any interesting messages in your logs ?

Comment: You should really know the basics what the system does when issuing the `service` command. (It uses the scripts in `/etc/init.d/...`. This is not very professional.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
restart() {
    [ "x$IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART" = "xyes" ] && save
    stop
    start
}
```

and

```
start() {
    # Do not start if there is no config file.
    [ ! -f "$IPTABLES_DATA" ] && return 6

    # check if ipv6 module load is deactivated
    if [ "${_IPV}" = "ipv6" ] \
        && grep -qIsE "^install[[:space:]]+${_IPV}[[:space:]]+/bin/(true|false)" /etc/modprobe.conf /etc/modprobe.d/* ; then
        echo $"${IPTABLES}: ${_IPV} is disabled."
        return 150
    fi

    echo -n $"${IPTABLES}: Applying firewall rules: "
```

If there is nothing changed in your scripts - it works. You just can't see it.

(rpm -V iptables)

What's the content of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` ?